Firebase Authentication Sign in with LinkedIn through OIDC get missing client secret exception
Setup
I have used the following steps to enable OIDC Sign-in method

I have setup OIDC authentication using LinkedIn as provider. In step 1, I choose "code flow" as Grant type, fill in Name, Client ID, Issuer as well as Client Secret.

I also set up a LinkedIn app using the Callback URL provided by OIDC configuration step 2. In my case, My callback URL is: https://my-firebase-ap-id.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
Steps to reproduce:

InitializeApp using js SDK firebase@10.11.1
create a function, which is called when User click the button "Login win LinkedIn"

const signInWithLinkedIn = async () => {
  console.log("Sign in with LinkedIn");
  const provider = new OAuthProvider("oidc.linkedin");
  const auth = getAuth();
  await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  console.log("Sign in with LinkedIn done");
};


The OAuth flow started successfully, however, after I give consent to the app, a Firebase error occurs


firebase_auth.js?v=ffaae778:672 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error getting access token from https://www.linkedin.com/oauth, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://my-firebase-app-id.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_request&error_description=A%20required%20parameter%20%22client_secret%22%20is%20missing, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, permissionsPolicies=[], headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK

which indicates error response: A required parameter "client_secret" is missing.
After inspecting the network request, this error comes from  a API call to:
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=a-key-string
Question
I have set the client secret in the OIDC configuration, why the API call failed with bad request, complaining that the client secret is missing??

+1 also seeing the same error with LinkedIn OIDC login... "client_secret" is missing (despite this being added to the firebase config).
update: have verified is still an issue on latest javascript SDK version 10.12.2

Hi @Fringley. I contacted the Firebase support team and they confirm this is a bug in the callback endpoint. The workaround is to create custom authentication until they fix the issue...

Thanks @fuyi - i also did the same and have also received the same response!  I think it's good they have acknowledged the issue and hopefully now its not just one report it will get addressed soon :)

Hi, the problem still exists on Firebase SDK v10.13.1. Google support team suggested the following workaround:
You can try by getting the LinkedIn ID Token on your own, I found some client libraries that might be useful for that. Then you can use the ID Token to create a firebase credential as is described in Handle the sign-in flow manually.
Hope this will be natively fixed soon.

Same issue here and haven't heard from Firebase. However, I have implemented a solution that worked partially with Firebase, find below:
// Step 1 :: Add listener to event (invoke it only once - component init)
async _loginLinkedInResponse(code: string) {
// API To send the Code returned by the pop up and #serverside check 
const result = await this._authApi.loginLinkedin(code);

const { id_token: idToken } = result;

// Firebase OIDC
const provider = new OAuthProvider("oidc.linkedin");
const credential = provider.credential({
    idToken: idToken,
});

signInWithCredential(this._auth, credential)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log({ result });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle error.
    });

}
// Step 2 :: Call the Linkedin Popup
  const clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
  const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('REDIR_URL');
  const scope = encodeURIComponent('email profile openid');
  const state = 'STATE';
  const linkedInUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&state=${state}`;

  const width = 600;
  const height = 600;
  const left = (window.screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
  const top = (window.screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

  window.open(linkedInUrl, 'LinkedIn Auth', `width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`);

// STEP 3 :: REDIR_URL (e.g. in angular)
export class AuthorizationComponent implements OnInit {
private _activatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
ngOnInit(): void {
const code = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('code');
window.opener.postMessage({ type: 'auth', code }, window.location.origin);
window.close();

}
}
// # SERVERSIDE CHECK (example in nodejs)
`
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');
const data = {
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: 'YOUR_AUTH_CODE',
  redirect_uri: 'SAME_REDIR_CALLBACK',
  client_id: 'YOUR_LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID',
  client_secret: 'YOUR_LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET'
};

axios.post('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken',         qs.stringify(data), {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}).then(response => {
   //SEND BACK TO FRONT END
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Error fetching access token:', error.response ?     error.response.data : error.message);
});

`
